# Designing an allpass IIR filter with arbitrary phase response

Tags: filter-design, infinite-impulse-response, phase

could you tell me step by step the algorithm to design an arbitrary phase response IIR allpass filter design ?

I know [Matlab uses a "brute force" algorithm to find an arbitrary group delay response](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/iirgrpdelay.html) but how do they do that?

Answer (score 2):

Depends a bit on what exactly you are trying to do. Generally, strict all-pass filters have reciprocal zeros and poles. This will always result in 180 phase shift per filter order so an arbitrary phase response that's strictly allpass cannot be designed. Example: let's say you want something that's in phase at DC,  sits at -90 degrees in the band and then goes slowly back to zero at Nyquist: this can't be implemented using strict all-passes.

Of course you can always approximate but the best method tends to depend on the specifics of your design problems and what types of errors you can tolerate.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Do you know the function from Matlab iirgrpdelay ? It designs an arbitrary allpass filter with iterations. I want to match the phase of an IIR to make it almost linear. I know it's possible because i've seen it in some implementations. I can tolerate some errors but i want to have the maximum linearity in the phase response. thanks. Jeff